# ValueError: time data '{0}' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

I'm trying to INSERT to MySQL from a CSV file, first 'column' in the file is a date in this format:

```
    31/08/2017;
```

then my column in the table is set as YYYY-MM-DD

this is my code:

```
    import datetime
    import csv
    import MySQLdb
    ...
    insertionSQL="INSERT INTO transactions (trans_date, trans_desc, trans_amnt) VALUES(" + datetime.datetime.strptime('{0}', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ",{2},{3}), row)"
    cur.execute(insertionSQL)
```

I get the following error from my python script:

```
    (data_string, format))
    ValueError: time data '{0}' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

Comment: Ok. First of all, this seems unrelated to MySQL, because `datetime.datetime.strptime('{0}', '%d/%m/%Y')` gives that warning.

Comment: You should format strings, i.e. '{0}'.format(your_date_string).

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the date formatting logic during the query execution. You can't just put the logic in your insertion query string and expect it to work (as you can see, `strptime` is trying to convert the string `{0}` into a date object according to the date format string, which obviously cannot work!)

```
    insertionSQL = "INSERT INTO transactions (trans_date, trans_desc, trans_amnt) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"
    ... # read csv
    # Reformat the date on the actual data from the CSV!
    csv_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(csv_date, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # Now all of your input data is formatted correctly, execute the prepared statement.
    cursor.execute(insertionSQL, (csv_date, csv_desc, csv_amnt))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was missing delimiter=";" so the csv reader took entire row as one value